# What makes Struts tightly coupled

Tags: struts

I've been trying to find a clear answer to this question for a while but haven't had any luck.  I need to know why Struts is tightly coupled? which component of struts makes it tightly coupled.

Comment: You should state which version of Struts you're talking about; they're wildly different, and the answer depends a lot on which version you care about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this great [Mkyong article](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-loosely-coupled-example/) discusses, what makes Struts tightly coupled is not the *presence* of something but rather the *absence* of something.  Struts is basically a web UI framework, and it can be compared to Spring MVC.  However, unlike Spring, Struts has no out-of-the-box support for dependency injection.  As a result, this means that when using Struts your entire code may have to be changed if a given depenency changes.  Another way of saying this is that the components you use in Struts are tightly coupled to the framework.

Comment: It would be better to note that S2 is completely different framework than S1 and is NOT tightly coupled.

Comment: What is coupled is rarely change, and this doesn't answer the question, because OP needs to know which components of the framework are coupled.

Comment: This is a different question, OP has asked *which component of struts makes it tightly coupled*. He wants to know about struts framework deeper rather than dependency injection mechanisms used by other frameworks like Spring. And Spring is not a rule of thumb providing these mechanisms.

Comment: Well, while DI can be used and still makes components tightly coupled.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of looking at this question:

1. Struts 1 *itself* is tightly-coupled, and
2. Struts 1 is tightly-coupled to the servlet spec

**Issue #1**

Eliminating this is trivial; use a supported version of Spring, and you have all the DI you need at the *application* level, e.g., you can inject your services, wire things with AOP, etc.

At the *framework* level you don't have the same flexibility. You cannot arbitrarily replace Struts 1 framework components. That's why custom request processors and action base classes are the first approach when framework-level functionality is needed–there's nowhere else to put it.

**Issue 2**

Eliminating issue #2 is less trivial: Struts artifacts all reference servlet spec artifacts, like the HTTP request and response. If you want to abstract that away, e.g., for easier testing, or business logic reuse, you must do so manually.

An example would be to marshal request parameters (e.g., form values) into a domain object or a simple map, and pass that to your domain logic.

Struts 1 was written before DI/IoC was what the cool kids were doing, before strict layer isolation was common, etc. It was written *early*. It carried that baggage on through the years because backwards compatibility is a thing.

You could argue that the coupling to the servlet spec is good or bad: it's really a matter of where the isolation between business logic and the web app occurs, who is responsible for it, and how do you want to test it.

Unit-testing a Struts 1 action is kind of a PITA. If all it does is handle the web-app-to-business-logic marshalling it's argiable they don't *need* to be unit tested: the business logic does, but the Struts 1 layer could be tested via an integration test at the web app level. (I'd argue that even makes sense, and I feel much the same way about Struts 2 action testing–but S2 actions are so easy to test (barring heavy interceptor interaction and a few other less-common things) that the differentiation is less important.

Comment: What is coupled is rarely change, and this doesn't answer the question, because OP needs to know which components of the framework are coupled. One more thing that differentiate it from tightly coupled to loosely coupled you can use transparently.

Comment: @RomanC *All* S1 components are coupled to the servlet spec. Please honor your agreement.